# Custom CSS for Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, text-formatting

I have installed a Wordpress plugin, called IgniteUp and I want to emphasize some words by using a heavy weight (900). But no matter what I try, the thickest font weight I get is Bold (this works when I use `<strong>`). I tried using `<bolder>`, `<thicker>` and others but it's not working.
I'm using the font Lato. Thanks!

Comment: What font are you using? What font files do you have available for it on your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-weight: 900` will only work by first referencing the font with that weight - from Google Fonts this would be something like:

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Then you can write a CSS style like:

```
strong {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
}
```